# Plain (non-HTML) error pages in REST api

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm writing a simple REST service with Flask. When an exception occurs in my code, I get a nice error message and an interactive debugger in my browser. However, if I call the service from the command line (e.g. with curl), or in my unit tests, and something fails, I still get the formatted (HTML) error message. I remember that I sometimes got a plain text message instead (basically just the Python error + traceback), and I don't know how Flask decides to serve plain text or HTML.

How do I make it so that Flask returns plain (non-interactive, non-HTML) error messages when accessed without a browser?

Answer (score 7):

To handle exceptions in production mode, register error handler for 500 status code.  From it you can return anything you want.  Here's an example that returns exception itself as plain text:

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def error_500(exception):
    return str(exception), 500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
```

If it's API you're writing, returning JSON encoded data as `application/json` may be more appropriate.

Comment: Regarding the JSON output, you'll need to jsonify as normal:
`return jsonify({"error": str(exception)}), 500, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`

Answer (score 5):

Set `app.debug = False` to turn off the fancy error reporting. The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode) has more on debug mode.