# How to return JSON response for exceptions in Python?

Tags: python, flask

I am using exception handling classes e.g., `werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest` to raise exceptions when they occur. I want to return a JSON to the user when an exception is encountered. For example,

```
{
'http_response': 400,
'message':'error message'
}
```

By default, the user gets an HTML error message like:

```
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>error message</p>
```

Should I create a custom subclass of BadRequest and JSONify the response there? I am reluctant to do it this way because I would have to create subclasses for all the types of exceptions there are. Is there any existing library or a better way to do this?

Comment: This was helpful for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332056/global-error-handler-for-any-exception

Comment: @JacobIRR, thanks for the lead. But how do I have the handle_error() method used when I raise an exception anywhere in the project? I still get HTML response. Do I have to explicitly write the @errorhandlers? Or subclass the exception classes maybe?